# Object getting Null seems like deserialization issue in Hangfire

Tags: c#, hangfire

It seems like Hangfire is unable to deserialize my original `Scheduler` object with all its state, whose Execute method I am calling in `BackgroundJob.Enqueue()` as shown below:

```
Scheduler = new FileInFileOut
{
    FileIn = new FileInput()
    {
        FileName = "SampleInput.txt",
        DirectoryPath = @"C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\iRule",
        FileFormat = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"X", "ParseInt(input.Substring(0, 2))"},
            {"Y", "ParseInt(input.Substring(3, 2))"},
            {"Z", "ParseInt(input.Substring(6, 2))"},
        }
    },
    FileOut = new FileOutput()
    {
        FileName = "SampleOutput.txt",
        DirectoryPath = @"C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\iRule"
    },
    Trigger = new FireAndForgetTrigger()
};
BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => Scheduler.Execute());
```

The Scheduler is of type IScheduler as shown below:

```
public interface IScheduler
{
    IEntityBaseDef EntityItemBase { get; set; }
    ITrigger Trigger { get; set; }
    RuleApp RuleApp { get; set; }
    Type JobType { get; set; }
    void Execute();
}

[Serializable()]
[DataContract()]
public abstract class Scheduler : EntityModel, IScheduler
{
    public abstract void Execute();
}

[Serializable()]
[DataContract()]
public class FileInFileOut : Scheduler, IFileInFileOut
{
    private FileInput _fileIn;
    public FileInput FileIn
    {
        get { return _fileIn; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _fileIn, value); }
    }

    private FileOutput _fileOut;
    public FileOutput FileOut
    {
        get { return _fileOut; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _fileOut, value); }
    }

    public override void Execute()
    {
        // ERROR on below line, FileIn object is null 
        var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(FileIn.DirectoryPath); 
        var files = directoryInfo.GetFiles();
        if (FileIn.SearchSubDirectories)
        {
            var directories = directoryInfo.GetDirectories().Flatten(x => x.GetDirectories());
        }
    }
}
```

My Current Scheduler Publishing Logic:

```
public void Publish()
{
    if (Scheduler != null)
    {
        var trigger = Scheduler.Trigger;
        if (trigger is IFireAndForgetTrigger)
        {
            BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => Scheduler.Execute());
        }
        else if (trigger is IDelayedTrigger)
        {
            var delayedTrigger = (IDelayedTrigger)trigger;
            BackgroundJob.Schedule(() => Scheduler.Execute(), delayedTrigger.Delay);
        }
    }
}
```

Is it some kind of deserialization issue? How to identify and correct this issue?

Comment: Well, you have removed the code that probably triggers the exception according to your stacktrace. I mean the code inside the FileInFileOut.Execute method. I suggest to use the debugger to check what happen there

Comment: Thanks, I could able to debug and find the actual line of the error, added some more code to highlight the error. Please guide what is the cause of FileIn object getting null. Although it's marked as Serializable already.

Comment: Negative vote, what's wrong with the question?

Comment: It can't be a serialize/deserialize issue since none is taking place. It inspects the expression and extracts the types and methods called. `Scheduler` is abstract. which means it cannot be instantiated. that is your problem there

Comment: This question is incomplete and open to assumptions. provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hangfire does not attempt to store the state of the FileInFileOut object when the Enqueue method is called. It recreates the FileInFileOut object on the worker using a parameterless constructor (or one with parameters using a IOC activator) and then calls the method from your Enqueue expression. This results in the null reference (FileIn / FileOut not set).

You could modify your FileInFileOut method to pass the FileIn and FileOut objects to the Execute method (using a more functional programming approach). This may break other parts of your program so it's probably more appropraite to create a second wrapper class that instantiates the FileInFileOut object for you like:

```
public class FileInFileOutTasks
{
    public FileInFileOutTasks()
    {

    }
    public void RunExecute(FileIn fileIn, FileOut, fileout)
    {
        var scheduler = new FileInFileOut { FileIn = fileIn, FileOut = fileOut };
        scheduler.Execute();
    }
}
```

You would then call:

```
BackgroundJob.Enqueue<FileInFileOutTasks>(x => x.RunExecute(fileIn, fileOut));
```

and not even create the FileInFileOut object in your code if you didn't want to (just the FileIn / FileOut objects to be passed to the wrapper).

Comment: I wonder why Hangfire is not able to recreate the same instance of FileInFileOut object that's kind of weird that its calling Execute on an altogether different object instead of one who invoked. There must have been some way because otherwise, I need to change my design strategy drastically.

Comment: I think it was probably a design decision to keep the setup as straightforward and simple as possible. Hangfire is just the job scheduler. The implementation is responsible for managing the state. Even if Hangfire did deserialize your class for you and recreate the state I think there would be a lot of confusion around concurrency. The objects would just be copies and not the same object so changes in state would only be local to that instance.

Comment: Absolutely.  Just think about it...  If you schedule a job for tomorrow and restart your app between now and then, you literally *cannot* have the same object instance.  The answer from @playsted is good advice.  Hangfire serialises method invocations, and it uses IOC or a parameterless constructor to create the class instance housing the method.  So either pass your arguments through to the method or have a wrapper class & method which does the class instance construction and so on from there from arguments you pass to it.