# How to call another method using hangfire recurring Job?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-2.0, background-process, hangfire

I have implemented a method name `GetApiData()`. I want to call this method per minute using `hangfire` recurring job. But when I call this method it's showing the error

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: method
   at Hangfire.Common.Job..ctor(Type type, MethodInfo method, Object[] args)
   at Hangfire.Common.Job.FromExpression(LambdaExpression methodCall, Type explicitType)
   at Raasforce.Crm.ContactRepositoriesAppService.APIDataBackgroundJob() in E:\RaasforceCorp\RaasforceCorp\aspnet-core\src\Raasforce.Application\Crm\ContactRepositoriesAppService.cs:line 795
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass33_0.<WrapVoidMethod>b__0(Object target, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionMethodExecutor.VoidResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
```

What will be the proper syntax? It is showing run time error.

```
public void APIDataBackgroundJob()
{
    RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(()=>GetApiData(),Cron.Minutely);//This line is showing error
}
```

Comment: try `var myInstance= new MyClass(); RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(myInstance.GetApiData,Cron.Minutely);`

Comment: can you share stack trace or what does `GetApiData` method do?

Comment: it takes 5 data at a time from another api in insert in diffrent tables in database  @Aarif

Comment: can you add the code to the question?

Comment: I can't add that method implementation for privacy issue. I checked that get GetAPIDataMethod(). The method signature is like this -
`private async Task GetApiData()`
its working correctly.Only i need to call this method every minute

Comment: there's really nothing I can tell from the given code that may be causing a runtime error

Comment: I already added full error message in the problem definition.

Comment: Without the code, the error is meaningless. Voting to close.

Comment: try providing method's reference instead of invoking it `()=>GetApiData`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use like this

```
public void APIDataBackgroundJob()
{
    RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<YourClassContainsThisMethod>(service=>service.GetApiData(),Cron.Minutely);//This line is showing error
}
```

and be aware you can only use public methods

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be caused by a serialization issue. Take a look at this: [Object getting Null seems like deserialization issue in Hangfire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44590115/object-getting-null-seems-like-deserialization-issue-in-hangfire).

Short summary:
Try to pass all the instance variables you use inside `GetApiData()` as parameters to this method.